# Postgresql. One process insert, second try to select but not found

Tags: javascript, postgresql, tomcat

Strange situation.

I try to start chat application.
I use postgresql 9.3 and tomcat as web server.

What is happens when one browser sending message another:

1 - Broswer A send message to server (tomcat)

2 - Tomcat put msg into database and get his id

```
INSERT INTO messages VALUES('first message') returning into MSGID id
```

3 - Tomcat resend message to Browser B (websocket recipient)

4 - Browser B send system answer: MSGID_READED

5 - Tomcat update database message

```
UPDATE messages SET readtime = now() WHERE id = MSGID
```

All works, but sometimes at point 5 update can't find message by MSGID...

Very strange, coz at point 2 I getting message record ID, but at 5, not.

May postgresql write slowly and this record not allow (not visible) from parallel db connection?

**UPDATE**

I found solution for me, just put insert inside begin/exception/end block.

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO messages (...)
        VALUES (...)
        RETURNING id INTO MSGID;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN unique_violation THEN
     -- nothing
END;
```

**UPDATE 2**

In detail tests above changes with BEGIN block has no effects.
Solution in Javascript! I sent websocket messages from other thread and problem solved!

```
// WebSocket send message function
// Part of code. so is a web socket
send = function(msg) {
    if (msg != null && msg != '') {
        var f = function() {
            var mm = m;
//            JCC.log('SENT: [' + mm + ']');
            so.send(mm);
        };
        setTimeout(f, 1);
    }
};
```

Comment: Are steps 1 and 2 inside an uncommitted transaction, so step 5 cannot see the results until the first transaction commits? Check your "autocommit" settings in tomcat etc.

Comment: Tried defaultAutoCommit="true" on Resource jndi pool - nothing changes

Comment: Yes, you are right, postgres late with transaction. I insert delay one second before READED answer and now all works!

Comment: You may be facing `write skew`. Check [Serializable Snapshot Isolation](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI). One solution is to implement a retry handler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is that normally writers do not block readers.  This means that your first insert happens, and the second insert fires before the first one commits.  This introduces a race condition in your application which introduces the problem you see.

Your best issue here is either to switch to serializable snapshot isolation or to do what you have done and do exception handling on the insert.  One way or another you end up with additional exception handling that must be handled (if serializable, then a serialization failure exception may sometimes happen and you may have to wait for it).

In your case, despite the performance penalty of exception handling in plpgsql, you are best off to do things the way you are currently doing them because that avoids the locking issues and waiting for the transaction to complete.